# Remove Spaces Between Specific Characters Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I want to do something like this in Notepad++.

Example text:

Text1~Text2   ~Text3   ~Text4   ~

How can I remove the spaces before ~ character and replace ~ with comma instead using Notepad++? The output should be:

Sample Output:

Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is try to replace all on the application.

Use Ctrl + H key

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29598765)

Comment: @slideshowp2 my solution can solve his problem

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a simple replacement. Use `Ctrl + H` key combination which will show up find and replace popup. In the first input box write  `~` and in the second one write `,` and then click on `replace all` button.
If your text is more complicated than what you've told, give us a piece of text so that I can tell you a better way which is the use of `Regular Expression`.